# Packaging Predicate Functors

Tags: c++, predicate, functor

I'm wondering about conventions and best practices regarding the packaging of predicate functors.  For example, given a class like:

```
class Timer
{
public:
  Timer(const std::string& name, int interval);
  bool nameIs(const std::string& name) const;
private:
  std::string name_;
  int interval_;
};
```

that is (in one case) used in class `TimerVec`:

```
class TimerVec
{
public:
  typedef std::vector<Timer>::iterator iterator;``
  <... ctors, etc ...>
  iterator findByName(const std::string& name);
private:
  std::vector<Timer> timers_;
};
```

and has a predicate functor like:

```
class TimerNameIs
{
public:
  TimerNameIs(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
  bool operator()(const Timer& t) { return t.nameIs(name_); }
private:
  const std::string& name_;
};
```

I can think of a number of places to put the functor code, some being:

1. In the header file immediately following the declaration of Timer
2. Nested inside Timer (i.e. so the ref becomes `Timer::TimerNameIs`)
3. Nested inside TimerVec (currently the only user)
4. In an anonymous namespace ahead of the implementation for `TimerVec::findByName` (again the only place it's used)

While any of these would be adequate I'm rather drawn to #2, but it's not something I've ever seen done.  Are there any concrete reasons favoring a particular option?

Comment: If it is only used by one function, I'd use #4 for the time being. In fact it is possible that you don't need a functor at all (C++11 lambda etc). If you discover other uses later, it should be simple to refactor. - I would definitely not use #3 or any other option that would force unrelated code to be recompiled if I choose to refactor.

Comment: @UncleBens The lambda would clearly be the best solution, were it available in this case.  But +1 because I should've thought of it, but didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is open to debate.  I prefer to create a nested class.  This way a functor that is intended only to work with a particular type of object is namespace-scoped within that object.

I also generally name the predicate `match_xxx` where `xxx` is the parameter I'm matching on.

To wit:

```
class Timer
{
  // ...
public:
  class match_name : public std::unary_function<Timer, bool>
  {
  public:
    match_name(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
    bool operator()(const Timer& t) { return t.nameIs(name_); }
  private:
    const std::string& name_;
  };
};
```

...which is utilized thusly:

```
std::find_if( v.begin(), v.end(), Timer::match_name("Flibbidy") );
```

I prefer this method because the semantics of `Timer::match_name("Flibbidy")` are exceedingly clear when looking at this code 6 months later.

I also am careful to derive my functor from `std::unary_function` (although my derivation above might have the parameters reversed).

Comment: I knew any answer would be debatable, but your reasoning is sound.  And the advice to derive from unary_function is spot-on.  All this and you confirmed my bias :)

Answer (score 1):

Me, personally, in it's own header and cpp files. Using `#include "Timer.h"` in the `TimerNameIs`header file:

```
#include "Timer.h"
#include <string>

class TimerNameIs
{
    public:
        TimerNameIs(const std::string& name) : name_(name) {}
        bool operator()(const Timer& t) { return t.nameIs(name_); }
    private:
        const std::string& name_;
};
```

Doing this, you isolate Timer and TimerNameIs from one to the other.

Comment: +1 'cause I should've considered this also, but didn't.  The style of the project is that related classes are grouped into source files.  Also I'm not a big fan of the Java-style one-class-per-source-file model.  The fact of the matter is that Timer and TimerNameIs are inexorably coupled, so why not have the source grouping acknowledge that?

Comment: @rlduffy so, use second option. This way `TimeVec` can use it without problems. Thinking in future developments and uses, don't use 3rd option.