# std::find_if in a multimap returns error with a functor

Tags: c++, stl, functor

In the following code snippet, I try to find values in a multimap that are equal to the value of myPairA.second which correspond to int f = 0. However in the std::find_if STL algorithm, this shows an error :

```
 /usr/include/c++/5/bits/predefined_ops.h:234:30: error: no match for call to ‘(EqualFunctor<int>) (std::pair<const int, int>&)’
   { return bool(_M_pred(*__it)); }
                               ^`

 multimaps_2.cpp:12:10: note: candidate: bool EqualFunctor<T>::operator()(std::pair<const int, T*>) [with T = bool operator() (std::pair<const int, T*> myPair)
```

Here's my program: (the line with the std::find_if creates an error)
**See 2nd version below**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
class EqualFunctor
{
    T *t_;
public:
    EqualFunctor(T *t) : t_(t) {}
    bool operator() (std::pair<const int, T*> myPair)
    { return myPair.second == t_; }    
};

int main()
{
    // h, i & j are duplicates of f and g
    int f = 0, g = 1,
        h = 0, i = 1, j = 1;

    // declare five pairs
    std::pair<const int, int> myPairA (1, f),
                              myPairB (2, g),
                              myPairC (3, h),
                              myPairD (4, i),
                              myPairE (5, j);

    std::multimap<int, int> myMultimap;

    // insert pairs above in multimap with the exception of myPairA

    myMultimap.insert(myPairB);
    myMultimap.insert(myPairC);
    myMultimap.insert(myPairD);
    myMultimap.insert(myPairE);

    std::multimap<int, int>::iterator it;

    // pointer to f = 0, since the EqualFunctor class accepts a pointer
    int *ptrMyPairA = &myPairA.second;

    // find in multimap the pair that is equal to f, ie myPairA.second
    // with the EqualFunctor class 
    // Problem is here
    it = std::find_if(myMultimap.begin(), myMultimap.end(),
              EqualFunctor<int>(ptrMyPairA));

    // print to screen 
    std::cout << (*it).second << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

The desired output would be to show `0` at the screen which corresponds to the first occurrence of a duplicate in the multimap. (myPairC.second which is equal to int h = 0)

I've tried to read other posts related to this [stackoverflow](https://www.stackoverflow.com/q/7746273) question but it hasn't helped me solve it.
Also my question is almost identical to this one on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49677455/) but it still
doesn't help solving the issue.
Thanks

**EDIT**:
changing `std::pair<const int, int>` to `std::pair<const int, int*>` still gives an error:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

template <typename T>
class EqualFunctor
{
    T *t_;
public:
    EqualFunctor(T *t) : t_(t) {}
    bool operator() (std::pair<const int, T*> myPair)
    { return myPair.second == t_; }    
};

int main()
{
    // h, i & j are duplicates of f and g
    int f = 0, g = 1,
        h = 0, i = 1, j = 1;

    int *ptrF = &f, *ptrG = &g,
        *ptrH = &h, *ptrI = &i, *ptrJ = &j;
    // declare five pairs 
    std::pair<const int, int*> myPairA (1, ptrF),
                               myPairB (2, ptrG),
                               myPairC (3, ptrH),
                               myPairD (4, ptrI),
                               myPairE (5, ptrJ);

    std::multimap<int, int> myMultimap;

    // insert pairs above in multimap with the exception of myPairA

    myMultimap.insert(myPairB);
    myMultimap.insert(myPairC);
    myMultimap.insert(myPairD);
    myMultimap.insert(myPairE);

    std::multimap<int, int>::iterator it;

    // find in multimap the pair that is equal to f, ie myPairA.second
    // with the EqualFunctor class 
    // Problem is here
    it = std::find_if(myMultimap.begin(), myMultimap.end(),
                      EqualFunctor<int>(myPairA.second));

    // print to screen 
    std::cout << (*it).second << std::endl;    
    return 0;
}
```

gives an error `no viable overloaded '='` on the line where std::find_if is.

Comment: The element type of the map isn't `pair<const int, int*>`, it's `pair<const int, int>` as you have written. Your functor takes the former which is why it doesn't work.

Comment: `EqualFunctor::operator()( std::pair<const int, T*> myPair)` accepts pointer as a second parameter, how you expect it to work?

Comment: @0x499602D2: So why don't you make that an answer.

Comment: This does not compile. You are trying to insert `pair<const int, int*>` into a `multimap<int, int>`. [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Y0bVR6hHcjQSwEAh).

Comment: `auto` for the win! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

0x499602D2 already explained the problem in the comment, so please wait if he posts an answer before accepting any other replay.

```
The element type of the map isn't pair<const int, int*>, 
it's pair<const int, int> as you have written. 
Your functor takes the former which is why it doesn't work.
```

You can find the fixed code on [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZK1SWSp0ErmvAIrt). I decided to post an answer to show the fixed code, and additionally how the code can be simplified using brace initialization, lambda, `auto` and constructor deduction:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>

template <typename K, typename V>
class EqualFunctor
{
    V t_;
public:
    EqualFunctor(V t) : t_(t) {}
    bool operator() (std::pair<K const, V> const& myPair)
    { return myPair.second == t_; }    
};

int main()
{
    // use C++17 constructor deduction
    auto const myPairA = std::pair(1, 0);

    auto const myMultimap = std::multimap<int,int>{ {2,1}, {3,0}, {4,1}, {5,1}};

    // find in multimap the pair that is equal to f, ie myPairA.second
    // with the EqualFunctor class 
    // Problem is here
    auto it = std::find_if(myMultimap.begin(), myMultimap.end(),
                      EqualFunctor<int,int>(myPairA.second));

    // print to screen 
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;    

    // simpler with lambda
    it = std::find_if(myMultimap.begin(), myMultimap.end(),
                      [&myPairA](auto const& x) {return x.second == myPairA.second;} );

    // print to screen 
    std::cout << it->second << std::endl;    

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: plus1 for posting the answer instead of commenting and mentioning lambda.

Comment: Nit: make the `operator()` const.

Comment: thanks @Jens & 0x499602D2, however I have difficulty using C++ > 11 since I can only compile with g++ -std=c++11 on linux (forgot to say in my post). Can you please still make a version with one typename in class and mainly C++11 stl algorithms?

Comment: @JassP You can find a C++11 version at https://wandbox.org/permlink/hm9bn8RVgfZTlcMG. Why do you want to `EqualFunctor` to have only one template parameter? It's more generic if you have template parameters for key and value types.